# select columns by rule and stack them in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
Area    RA  RI  WA  WI  NA  NI
3   3   1   4   2   2   1
2   2   1   3   1   2   1
3   2   1   3   2   2   1
2   2   1   3   1   1   1
2   2   1   3   2   1   1
2   2   1   2   1   2   1
2   3   1   2   1   2   1
3   1   1   2   2   1   1
2   2   1   1   1   2   1
2   2   1   2   1   2   1
3   1   1   3   1   1   1
```

I want to retain the first column and stack every two columns as:

```
Area    columan 1   Column 2
3   3   1
2   2   1
3   2   1
2   2   1
2   2   1
2   2   1
2   3   1
3   1   1
2   2   1
2   2   1
3   1   1
3   4   2
2   3   1
3   3   2
2   3   1
2   3   2
2   2   1
2   2   1
3   2   2
2   1   1
2   2   1
3   3   1
3   2   1
2   2   1
3   2   1
2   1   1
2   1   1
2   2   1
2   2   1
3   1   1
2   2   1
2   2   1
3   1   1
```

Your suggest highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the alternating columns using the recycling logical index (`c(TRUE, FALSE)` after subsetting the dataset without the first column (`df1[-1]`), `unlist` and cbind it with the first column.

```
d1 <- data.frame(Area = df1[,1], column1 = unlist(df1[-1][ c(TRUE, FALSE)]), 
           column2 = unlist(df1[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
row.names(d1) <- NULL
head(d1)
#  Area column1 column2
#1    3       3       1
#2    2       2       1
#3    3       2       1
#4    2       2       1
#5    2       2       1
#6    2       2       1
tail(d1)
#   Area column1 column2
#28    2       2       1
#29    2       2       1
#30    3       1       1
#31    2       2       1
#32    2       2       1
#33    3       1       1
```